# Visual Studio 2015 run and debug on different OS version simulators

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am developing a VB.Net based Windows8.1(10) Store application.

After published, I've found out that my App crashes on Windows8.1 while it works fine on Windows10.

So, I want to debug my App on the Windows8.1. However, I cannot find how to do so.

When I [Run] the App to [Simulator], it runs on clone of my computer, but I want to run it on other version of Windows.

Visual Studio 2015 is now installed on Windows10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work on Visual Studio, though not on the Universal/Modern App area.

This is not a supported scenario and there is no feature present in Windows that emulates or simulates previous versions of the "Modern" runtime environment.

The Simulator feature is actually a local-loopback Remote Desktop (Terminal Services) session and existed to make it easier to debug Modern applications given that they could only run in a fullscreen mode, however as this is no-longer the case (as apps are now floating windows) the utility of the Simulator is limited, and as you're discovering is not relevant to your problem.

The only solution I can recommend is to use Hyper-V (or another desktop virtualisation product, such as VirtualBox or VMWare if you don't want a hypervisor installed) to install a dedicated Windows 8.1 environment followed by installing the Visual Studio Remote Debugger.

Given the rapid adoption of Windows 10 (as it is provided as a recommended update to the majority of Windows 8.1 users) I don't personally recommend explicitly targeting the Windows 8.x "Modern" app environment unless you know you will have users or if it's a contract requirement.